# Angular 4 Dependency Injection: How to watch changes among different components on the same page

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

My Question: What is the best way to synchronize two components on the same page?

My Approach: From the Dependency Injection part of the Angular 4 home page I learned that services are singletons in their scope (defined by the `providers` keyword). Thus, I can think about sharing variables between components by injecting the same service and directly accessing the service variables. Therefore, I would need to bind my components click events to service functions that change service variables. This sounds like bad practice to me?!

Example: From the Angular tutorial: [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial). Assuming I want to have the dashboard on the same page as the heroes list by adding `<app-dashboard></app-dashboard>` at the end of heroes.component.html.

Say, e.g. I delete Bombasto in the heroes list, the dashboard doesn't change with the example approach. Following my idea, I would have to:

1. Make `heroes=Hero[]` being part of `HeroServices` provided by `AppModule`.
2. Rewrite the functions in `HeroService` to change the `heroes` variable of `HeroService`.
3. Access the list of heroes from within the `DashboardComponent` and `HeroesComponent` directly with `heroService.heroes` or with a customized get function (e.g. adding filters).

Anyone with a better approach?

Comment: Why does it sound like bad practice to you?

Comment: Because it defines 'semi'-global variables ... well actually I just realized, if I define everything with get..() functions things seem to work and I don't rely on these variables. However, the question is still: Is there another approach, or is this really the best practice?

Comment: In my opinion this is the best option. Especially when you are using multiple modules and provide the service at the correct level. Also, when using a Subject, you can make sure a component won't get the data which is emitted before the subscribe.

Comment: Ok thank you, than I'll go that way.